# How to get a local copy of a patch in the repo with mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Is there a command to import a patch already in the repository to your local sources with mercurial ?

Comment: You can try `pull` if you want that patch into another mercurial repository, or if you want the patch as some text file, an answer below by me will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `hg export -o filename` to do this.

```
$ mkdir repo
$ cd repo
$ hg init
$ echo a > a
$ hg add a
$ hg commit -m "Commit 0"
$ hg export -o patch.txt
```

If you open `patch.txt`, it will look like

```
# HG changeset patch
# User Your Name <your email address>
# Date 1482413390 -19800
#      Thu Dec 22 18:59:50 2016 +0530
# Node ID 6e46bc10f352958b841995d47e6944ae4e9ebd89
# Parent  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Commit 0

diff -r 000000000000 -r 6e46bc10f352 a
--- /dev/null   Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000
+++ b/a Thu Dec 22 18:59:50 2016 +0530
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+a
```

This is quite similar to what happens when you mail your patches to a mailing list. For more, you can do `hg help export` or go to [Tutorial Export](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TutorialExport).

You can then import it where ever you want by doing `hg import filename` and the patch will be applied to that repository.

```
$ cd ..
$ mkdir repo0
$ hg init
$ hg import ../repo/patch.txt
applying ../repo/patch.txt
$ hg tip
changeset:   0:6e46bc10f352
tag:         tip
user:        Your Name <your email address>
date:        Thu Dec 22 18:59:50 2016 +0530
summary:     Commit 0
$ ls
a
```

You can see the patch is applied to your new directory.